# Tailwind CSS columns in mega menu safari problem/bug?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have made a demo on Tailwind play. https://play.tailwindcss.com/2xRDmC52V7 It is simplified version of whats going on. This part is the mega menu opening, hence the `absolute` propery.

When using `absolute`, things get weird on Safari. I made the example in TailwindCSS since it is easy. The same problem exist with normal CSS. I am looking for the solution with either of them.

### Safari screenshot below.

See div with red border, it should be around the whole contents.

[image: Safari screenshot]

### Chrome screenshot below

This is how it should look like.

[image: Chrome screenshot]

### The problem

In safari the div does not take the widt of the content, so the menu items fall outside the container div. I cannot set a width since the menu is dynamic (the content lenght is different). And setting width the 100% does not work either since it takes the width of the parent menu item (which is very small).

How can I fix this without setting an explicit width?

#### Reproduction

```html
<div class="absolute">
  <div>
    <div class="flex flex-col flex-wrap bg-red-100 h-96 border-4 border-red-500">
      <div class="p-4">
        <div class="font-bold">Lorem ipsum 1</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
      </div>
      <div class="p-4">
        <div class="font-bold">Lorem ipsum 2</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
      </div>
      <div class="p-4">
        <div class="font-bold">Lorem ipsum 3</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
      </div>
      <div class="p-4">
        <div class="font-bold">Lorem ipsum 4</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
      </div>
      <div class="p-4">
        <div class="font-bold">Lorem ipsum 5</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
      </div>
      <div class="p-4">
        <div class="font-bold">Lorem ipsu.. 6</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<script>
  tailwind.config = {}
</script>
```

Comment: Tailwind only defines CSS classes, it generates CSS code. The generation of CSS code is independent of the browser. Therefore, there is some error in Safari that does not correctly determine the dimensions of a `flex` placed in an `absolute`.

Comment: Thanks @rozsazoltan fortunatly I know what Tailwind CSS is and how it works. I think your conclusion is right. Do you have any tips in which direction to look for a solution?

Comment: For example, there was a similar error in version 115 of Edge, but if I remember correctly, it was fixed in version 116.

Comment: Could you replace the code in each screenshot with the text equivalent? There is a block formatting tool in the editor. (Since the screenshots also show your result, you can just add code to the posts, rather than redoing the images).

Comment: The code was added by playground in the first sentence. It's really better if it's on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this classes:

```
<div class="absolute w-full max-w-2xl h-full">
    ... your html
```

This should ensure that the absolute div takes the full width, a max width and height of its parent.

I've made a demo on Tailwind play

https://play.tailwindcss.com/d3wCtO2I7P

Hope it helps.

Comment: I absolutely don't understand why the `max-w-2xl` is necessary. Using `w-full h-full` would be logical, but it doesn't solve the problem: it just creates another one, as seen in the photo. https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiMBL.png